# Understand the behavior for hub/switch in Cisco IP phone 7960

Tags: cisco

*Cisco IP phone 7960* has two RJ45 sockets at back panel. One of those ports has "10/100 SW" label above and other port has "10/100 PC" label. According to "Network Port 2 Device Type" under phone "Network Setup" menu it is a "Hub/Switch". If I view the MAC address table from switch where the phone is connected to, then I see following information:

```
Destination Address  Address Type  VLAN  Destination Port
-------------------  ------------  ----  --------------------
000a.b42f.54bb       Dynamic        105  FastEthernet0/2
0030.94c3.1597       Dynamic        105  FastEthernet0/2
0030.94c3.1597       Dynamic        909  FastEthernet0/2
```

*000a.b42f.54bb* is the MAC address of my PC and *0030.94c3.1597* is the MAC address of the phone.

Am I correct that *Cisco IP phone 7960* has a two port switch? Why is there a MAC address table entry for *0030.94c3.1597* in VLAN 105 when according to phone the operational VLAN ID is 909?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

It really is a 3 port switch:

- One port connects to the PC
- One port connects to the upstream switch
- One port connects internally to the phone

The reason you see the MAC address on V105 is that the internal switch sends CDP, LLDP, STP, etc on the native VLAN, using that MAC address.

Comment: Thanks! So am I correct that this three-port switch in phone is internally configured in a way that port which connects to PC is a trunk port with all the VLAN's allowed and native VLAN on this trunk port is the same as native VLAN in upstream switch port? VLAN ID 105 in my example. And phone switch port which connects to upstream switch is a trunk port with all the VLAN's enabled and native VLAN is 105? All the phone traffic is on VLAN 909.

Comment: Not quite.  the PC port is an access port (no trunking) and only native VLAN traffic is forwarded on it.  Everything else you said is correct.

Comment: Are you sure because I am able to create VLAN-interfaces in PC and I have connectivity on network layer on those VLAN-interfaces. For example I have an eth0.9 interface in PC which sends and receives tagged traffic in VLAN 9 and I am able to ping IP interface(SVI) VLAN9 in upstream switch. I can even create an eth0.909 interface, get the IP address from DHCP server in VoIP VLAN(909) and ping the VoIP DHCP server. I made an illustration to explain my comment: http://s29.postimg.org/nw9lawlhz/Cisco_phone_internal_switch.png

Comment: That's very interesting.  It "shouldn't" work that way, and the Cisco docs imply (but do not explicitly state) that it is only an access port.  But I admit I've never actually tried to do what you're doing, so maybe I've been operating on rumour all these years ;-p